# Lost or Forgotten SA Password - SQL Server 2016

Tags: sql-server

I installed MSSQL Server 2016 on Windows 10 Home, and created some databases. I then upgraded to Windows 10 Pro, and now since I am logging in to SQL as a different user (old user was local, new user is domain), it won't allow me to access my databases - I can't assign users to access them, I can't open them, I can't delete them.

I have tried:

- Creating a new SQL User, and assigning rights
- Logging into windows as the Local User (which has been removed; and cannot be re-created on the Local computer)
- Assigning rights with the Domain Admin User (in the Management Studio)

I don't know the `sa` credentials.

How can I get access to my databases?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's another method which may help you gain access to the **SQL Server** instance on your **Windows 10** Machine; I've not used this one but it may work as well.

> ### Reset Forgotten SA Password
>
> 1. Click **Start**, point to **Run** and type **cmd**, press <kbd>**Enter**</kbd> key.
>
> [image]
>
> 2. The command prompt will appear. Run the command:
>
>    `Osql –S john –E`
>
>    Replace john with your actual computer name.
> 3. Then type this command to change your forgotten SA password.
>
>    `EXEC sp_password NULL, ’123456’, ’sa’`
>
>    Replace 123456 with the password you want.
> 4. Type **Go** to make the change take effect.
> 5. Now you are able to log into the SA account with your new password!
>
> You can also use this method to change SQL Server passwords of other
>   user accounts. If you're still unable to reset the SA password or SA
>   account is locked out or disabled, please check out this article: [2
>   Methods to Unlock SQL Server SA Account When It's Locked
>   Out](http://www.top-password.com/knowledge/unlock-sql-server-sa-account.html).
>
> <sub>[source](http://www.top-password.com/knowledge/reset-sa-password-from-command-prompt.html)</sub>

Answer (score 3):

### SQL Express Batch Script: Add Account to SQL Server SysAdmin Role

Try this script and see if it adds the user account that you execute it as the sysadmin access to the SQL Server instance on your Windows machine. This will need to be saved to a `.cmd` or `.bat` file by renaming a text document and then it needs executed as a batch script.

I got this from GitHub ["Script to add the current user to the sysadmin role in SQL Server"](https://gist.github.com/wadewegner/1677788) a few years back and used it for an SQL Express install to grant the sysadmin access to a local admin account on a server. I saved it after confirming it worked it worked—so I'm sharing it with others here.

```
@echo off
:: 
:: ****************************************************************************
:: 
::    Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
::    This code is licensed under the Microsoft Public License.
::    THIS CODE IS PROVIDED *AS IS* WITHOUT WARRANTY OF
::    ANY KIND, EITHER EXPRESS OR IMPLIED, INCLUDING ANY
::    IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR
::    PURPOSE, MERCHANTABILITY, OR NON-INFRINGEMENT.
:: 
:: ****************************************************************************
:: 
:: CMD script to add a user to the SQL Server sysadmin role
:: 
:: Input:  %1 specifies the instance name to be modified. Defaults to SQLEXPRESS.
::         %2 specifies the principal identity to be added (in the form "<domain>\<user>").
::            If omitted, the script will request elevation and add the current user (pre-elevation) to the sysadmin role.
::            If provided explicitly, the script is assumed to be running elevated already.
:: 
:: Method: 1) restart the SQL service with the '-m' option, which allows a single connection from a box admin
::            (the box admin is temporarily added to the sysadmin role with this start option)
::         2) connect to the SQL instance and add the user to the sysadmin role
::         3) restart the SQL service for normal connections
:: 
:: Output: Messages indicating success/failure.
::         Note that if elevation is done by this script, a new command process window is created: the output of this
::         window is not directly accessible to the caller.
:: 
::

setlocal
set sqlresult=N/A
if .%1 == . (set /P sqlinstance=Enter SQL instance name, or default to SQLEXPRESS: ) else (set sqlinstance=%1)
if .%sqlinstance% == . (set sqlinstance=SQLEXPRESS)
if /I %sqlinstance% == MSSQLSERVER (set sqlservice=MSSQLSERVER) else (set sqlservice=MSSQL$%sqlinstance%)
if .%2 == . (set sqllogin="%USERDOMAIN%\%USERNAME%") else (set sqllogin=%2)

:: remove enclosing quotes
for %%i in (%sqllogin%) do set sqllogin=%%~i
@echo Adding '%sqllogin%' to the 'sysadmin' role on SQL Server instance '%sqlinstance%'.
@echo Verify the '%sqlservice%' service exists ...
set srvstate=0
for /F "usebackq tokens=1,3" %%i in (`sc query %sqlservice%`) do if .%%i == .STATE set srvstate=%%j
if .%srvstate% == .0 goto existerror

:: elevate if <domain/user> was defaulted
if NOT .%2 == . goto continue
echo new ActiveXObject("Shell.Application").ShellExecute("cmd.exe", "/D /Q /C pushd \""+WScript.Arguments(0)+"\" & \""+WScript.Arguments(1)+"\" %sqlinstance% \""+WScript.Arguments(2)+"\"", "", "runas"); >"%TEMP%\addsysadmin{7FC2CAE2-2E9E-47a0-ADE5-C43582022EA8}.js"
call "%TEMP%\addsysadmin{7FC2CAE2-2E9E-47a0-ADE5-C43582022EA8}.js" "%cd%" %0 "%sqllogin%"
del "%TEMP%\addsysadmin{7FC2CAE2-2E9E-47a0-ADE5-C43582022EA8}.js"
goto :EOF

:continue
:: determine if the SQL service is running
set srvstarted=0
set srvstate=0
for /F "usebackq tokens=1,3" %%i in (`sc query %sqlservice%`) do if .%%i == .STATE set srvstate=%%j
if .%srvstate% == .0 goto queryerror

:: if required, stop the SQL service
if .%srvstate% == .1 goto startm
set srvstarted=1
@echo Stop the '%sqlservice%' service ...
net stop %sqlservice%
if errorlevel 1 goto stoperror

:startm
:: start the SQL service with the '-m' option (single admin connection) and wait until its STATE is '4' (STARTED)
:: also use trace flags as follows:
::     3659 - log all errors to errorlog
::     4010 - enable shared memory only (lpc:)
::     4022 - do not start autoprocs
@echo Start the '%sqlservice%' service in maintenance mode ...
sc start %sqlservice% -m -T3659 -T4010 -T4022 >nul
if errorlevel 1 goto startmerror

:checkstate1
set srvstate=0
for /F "usebackq tokens=1,3" %%i in (`sc query %sqlservice%`) do if .%%i == .STATE set srvstate=%%j
if .%srvstate% == .0 goto queryerror
if .%srvstate% == .1 goto startmerror
if NOT .%srvstate% == .4 goto checkstate1

:: add the specified user to the sysadmin role
:: access tempdb to avoid a misleading shutdown error
@echo Add '%sqllogin%' to the 'sysadmin' role ...
for /F "usebackq tokens=1,3" %%i in (`sqlcmd -S np:\\.\pipe\SQLLocal\%sqlinstance% -E -Q "create table #foo (bar int); declare @rc int; execute @rc = sp_addsrvrolemember '$(sqllogin)', 'sysadmin'; print 'RETURN_CODE : '+CAST(@rc as char)"`) do if .%%i == .RETURN_CODE set sqlresult=%%j

:: stop the SQL service
@echo Stop the '%sqlservice%' service ...
net stop %sqlservice%
if errorlevel 1 goto stoperror
if .%srvstarted% == .0 goto exit

:: start the SQL service for normal connections
net start %sqlservice%
if errorlevel 1 goto starterror
goto exit

:: handle unexpected errors
:existerror
sc query %sqlservice%
@echo '%sqlservice%' service is invalid
goto exit

:queryerror
@echo 'sc query %sqlservice%' failed
goto exit

:stoperror
@echo 'net stop %sqlservice%' failed
goto exit

:startmerror
@echo 'sc start %sqlservice% -m' failed
goto exit

:starterror
@echo 'net start %sqlservice%' failed
goto exit

:exit
if .%sqlresult% == .0 (@echo '%sqllogin%' was successfully added to the 'sysadmin' role.) else (@echo '%sqllogin%' was NOT added to the 'sysadmin' role: SQL return code is %sqlresult%.)
endlocal
pause
```